# rsync: How to exclude multiple file types?

Tags: bash, rsync, brace-expansion

This is with bash on a Mac running Catalina:

This works:

```
rsync -Pa --rsh="ssh -p 19991" --exclude '*.jpg' --exclude '*.mp4' pi@localhost:/home/pi/webcam /Volumes/Media/Webcam\ Backups/raspcondo/webcam/
```

These do not:

```
rsync -Pa --rsh="ssh -p 19991" --exclude={'*.jpg', '*.mp4'} pi@localhost:/home/pi/webcam /Volumes/Media/Webcam\ Backups/raspcondo/webcam/

rsync -Pa --rsh="ssh -p 19991" --exclude {'*.jpg', '*.mp4'} pi@localhost:/home/pi/webcam /Volumes/Media/Webcam\ Backups/raspcondo/webcam/
```

This is the output:

```
building file list ...
rsync: link_stat "/Users/mnewman/*.mp4}" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: link_stat "/Users/mnewman/pi@localhost:/home/pi/webcam" failed: No such file or directory (2)
0 files to consider
sent 29 bytes  received 20 bytes  98.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/main.c(996) [sender=2.6.9]
```

What am I doing wrong with the list of file types to exclude?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, your first example works - what's wrong with using that?

If you really don't want to do that, try `--exclude=*.{jpg,mp4}`, which will (in some shells) expand to `--exclude=*.jpg --exclude=*.mp4`, but note:

1. this is a **shell feature** called [Brace Expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)#Brace_expansion).  It is **not** a feature of rsync or rsync's filter rules.

   This can easily lead to confusion and "surprising" behaviour if you mistakenly think that rsync will use the braces itself (it won't, and can't, and never even sees the braces).
2. The expansion is done **before** rsync is executed.   rsync only sees, e.g.,  `--exclude=*.mp4` **because** there is no filename that matches that pattern in the current directory.
3. in the unlikely event that there are any filenames that match `--exclude=*.mp4` or `--exclude=*.jpg`, the brace expansion will expand to those exact filenames, without a wild-card.

e.g.

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ cd /tmp/test
$ echo rsync --exclude=*.{jpg,mp4}
rsync --exclude=*.jpg --exclude=*.mp4
```

so far, so good...but look what happens when there are filenames that actually match the brace expansions:

```
$ touch -- --exclude=foo.jpg
$ touch -- --exclude=bar.mp4
$ touch -- --exclude=foobar.mp4
$ echo rsync --exclude=*.{jpg,mp4}
rsync --exclude=foo.jpg --exclude=bar.mp4 --exclude=foobar.mp4
```

A better way to avoid typing lots of `--exclude` options would be to use an array and printf:

```
excludes=('*.mp4' '*.jpg')
rsync ...args... $([ "${#excludes[@]}" -gt 0 ] && printf -- "--exclude='%s' " "${excludes[@]}") ...more args...
```

This would result in a command line like:

```
rsync ...args... --exclude='*.mp4' --exclude='*.jpg'  ...more args...
```

Even better would be to use an array and process substitution to provide a "file" for `--exclude-from`.  e.g.

```
rsync ... --exclude-from=<([ "${#excludes[@]}" -gt 0 ] && printf -- '- %s\n' "${excludes[@]}") ...
```

Comment: +1 Nice that you gave several options.  Why is it generally better to provide a file containing a list to be used with `--exclude-from=file_list` instead of the previous (already satisfactory) solution, just based on the repetition of `--exclude=individual_file`, other than to avoid exceeding the cmd line's max length ? Also, can you explain the single hyphen in the format section of `printf -- '- %s\n' ...` in the last solution ?

Comment: @Cbhihe  `-` in an rsync filter file excludes matches, `+` includes them.  `man rsync` and search for `^FILTER RULES`

Comment: I asked the question for two reasons: 1) I wanted to find a shorter way to have a longer list of exclusions, and 2) I wanted to understand what was going one. This answer gave me both. I have a shorter way. And, I learned a few things. For that I am grateful.

Answer (score 3):

`--exclude={'*.jpg', '*.mp4'}` doesn't do [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion) because the opening and closing braces are in separate words. Brace expansion builds multiple words from a single word with a variable part. Remove the space.

```
rsync … --exclude={'*.jpg','*.mp4'} …
```

or

```
rsync … --exclude='*.'{jpg,mp4} …
```

The `=` after `--exclude` is necessary because the result of the shell expansion needs to be the two words `--exclude=*.jpg` and `--exclude=*.mp4`. Without a `=`, the expansion would be three words: `--exclude`, `*.jpg` and `*.mp4`.